# Combining Two Data Frames Horizontally in R

Tags: r

I would like to combine two data frames horizontally in R.

These are my two data frames:

dataframe 1:

```
veg     loc    quantity 

carrot  sak    three
pepper  lon    two
tomato  apw    five
```

dataframe 2:

```
seller   quantity  veg

Ben      eleven    eggplant  
Nour     six       potato
Loni     four      zucchini
Ahmed    two       broccoli
```

I want the outcome to be one data frame that looks like this:

```
veg       quantity

carrot    three
pepper    two
tomato    five
eggplant  eleven
potato    six
zucchini  four
broccoli  two
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Comment: Select the columns you want from the two data frames, then `rbind` them together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```r
library (tidyverse)

df1 <- df1%>%select(veg, quantity)
df2 <- df2%>%select(veg, quantity)

df3 <- rbind(df1, df2)
```

Answer (score 5):

The question says "horizontally" but from the sample output it seems that what you meant was "vertically".

Now, assuming the input shown reproducibly in the Note at the end, `rbind` them like this.  No packages are used and no objects are overwritten.

```
sel <- c("veg", "quantity")
rbind( df1[sel], df2[sel] )
```

If you like you could replace the first line of code with the following which picks out the common columns giving the same result for `sel`.

```
sel <- intersect(names(df1), names(df2))
```

### Note

```
Lines1 <- "veg     loc    quantity 
carrot  sak    three
pepper  lon    two
tomato  apw    five"

Lines2 <- "seller   quantity  veg
Ben      eleven    eggplant  
Nour     six       potato
Loni     four      zucchini
Ahmed    two       broccoli"

df1 <- read.table(text = Lines1, header = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE)
df2 <- read.table(text = Lines2, header = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE)
```